# Branching which can't be seen by compiler

Tags: java, if-statement

This is the snippet of code in Java language:

```
 public void name(){
int value = 9;
 int o;
if(value > 9)
 o = 5;

if(value <= 9)
o = 8;

System.out.println(o);
}
```

Why does compiler can't see the second if statement considering the last option of the value?
It won't compile.
Best regards

Comment: Error is : variable o might not have been initialized (System.out.println(o))

Comment: Why is it two if statements instead of an if..else?

Comment: I am just exploring the langue. There is no special reason for the two if statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler must treat `value` as changeable unless you say otherwise. Declaring it `final` [fixes the problem](http://ideone.com/TyYI0):

```
public void name(){
    final int value = 9;
    int o;
    if(value > 9) o = 5;
    if(value <= 9) o = 8;
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised it can't easily surmise that it's immutable in this scenario

Comment: @BrianAgnew I can only guess that the compiler is not allowed to treat the two reads of `value` in the two `if`s as accessing the same value (and therefore making the two conditions complementary).

Comment: Compiler can only operate on constant expressions when checking for definite assignment. Neither `value > 9` nor `value <= 9` are constant expressions unless `value` is constant variable which is essentially a `final` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the original version doesn't compile is that the JLS' "definite assignment" rules in [JLS section 16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html) say that `o` has not been definitely assigned.  The compiler reports this with an enigmatic message that says that "`o` may not have been initialized".

Now, anyone with simple deductive skills can see that the 2nd `if` condition is the negation of the 1st `if` condition, and therefore the variable will in fact always be initialized.  However, the JLS does not allow a compiler to make that deduction.  The JLS says this an error ...

There are a number of ways to fix this.  For example

- Assign something to `o` in the declaration.
- Replace the two `if` statements with a single `if` / `else` statement.
- Declare `value` as `final`.

The last fix is interesting.  The reason it works is that the JLS definite assignment rules *require* the compiler to take the value of a compile-time constant boolean-valued expression into account.

This statement (with the `final` added)

```
    final int value = 9;
```

means that `value` is a compile-time constant.  That means that `value <= 9` and `value > 9` are also compile-time constants.  The JLS definite assignment rules therefore state that `o` is definitely assigned after

```
    if(value <= 9) o = 8;
```

and can be used later without a compilation error.

---

The definite assignment rules are designed to prevent the use of uninitialized variables, and prevent blank `final` variables being initialized more than once.

The JLS's conservative treatment of expression values in the definite assignment rules is designed to avoid problems where one Java compiler deduces that something is definitely assigned, but another cannot.  The subcase of compile-time-constant expressions can be handled by simply evaluating the expression, and the JLS rules implicitly recognize this.

Answer (score 0):

During the compilation:

The compiler sees that you haven't initialized the variable 'o' and you are printing in the sysout.

you can achieve this :

```
public void name(){
int value = 9;
 int o;
if(value > 9)
 o = 5;

else
o = 8;

System.out.println(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize o before if statements after you declare it

```
o=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per JLS [(§16)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/defAssign.html#25979) every local variable and non-blank field must be *definitely assigned* before it can be used. The compiler does some basic static analysis to ensure it.

> The idea behind definite assignment is that an assignment to the local variable or blank final field must occur on every possible execution path to the access. Similarly, the idea behind definite unassignment is that no other assignment to the blank final variable is permitted to occur on any possible execution path to an assignment.

The static analyzer can only deduce values of constant expressions [($15.28)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#5313) which is not the case in your example.